# Rewriting same code in different methods

Tags: return-type

I have written the following code however trying to figure out how rewrite it by including parameters and boolean values if possible where main method requests user input and then calls upon the methods in order to produce the output:

```
import java.util.*;

class Congress 
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
            int age, citizen, i, r;
            citizen = 0;
            i = 0;
            r = 0;
            age = -1;
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println ("CONGRESS ELIGIBILITY");
            for (age = -1; age < 0; r++)
            {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.print ("Enter age of candidate: ");
                    age = keyboard.nextInt();
                    System.out.print ("Enter years of US citizenship: ");
                    citizen = keyboard.nextInt();
                    if (age <= 0)
                    {
                        System.out.print ("Please enter a proper age. ");
                    }
            }
            if (age >= 25 && citizen >= 7) {
                    i++;
            }
            if (age >= 30 && citizen >= 9) {
                    i++;
            }
            if (i == 0) {
            System.out.println ("The candidate is not eligible for election to either the House of Representatives or the Senate.");
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                    System.out.println ("The candidate is eligible for election to the House of Representatives but is not eligible for election to the Senate.");
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                    System.out.println ("The candidate is eligible for election to both the House of Representatives and the Senate.");
            }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/*
 * graphs - Congress.java, Nov 18, 2013 5:38:15 PM
 * 
 */
import java.util.*;

/**
 * The Class Congress.
 * 
 * @author Rajakrishna V. Reddy
 * @version 1.0
 *
 */
class Congress
{

```
/**
 * Eligible for senate.
 * 
 * @param age
 *            the age
 * @param lengthOfCitizenship
 *            the length of citizenship
 * @return true, if successful
 */
public static boolean eligibleForSenate(int age, int lengthOfCitizenship)
{
    return age >= 30 && lengthOfCitizenship >= 9;
}

/**
 * Eligible for house.
 * 
 * @param age
 *            the age
 * @param lengthOfCitizenship
 *            the length of citizenship
 * @return true, if successful
 */
public static boolean eligibleForHouse(int age, int lengthOfCitizenship)
{
    return age >= 25 && lengthOfCitizenship >= 7;
}

/**
 * The main method.
 * 
 * @param args
 *            the arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int age, citizen, i, r;
    citizen = 0;
    i = 0;
    r = 0;
    age = -1;
    final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("CONGRESS ELIGIBILITY");
    for (age = -1; age < 0; r++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter age of candidate: ");
        age = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter years of US citizenship: ");
        citizen = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (age <= 0)
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a proper age. ");
        }
    }
    try
    {
        keyboard.close();
    }
    finally
    {

    }
    final boolean eligibleForHouse = eligibleForHouse(age, citizen);
    final boolean eligibleForSenate = eligibleForSenate(age, citizen);
    if (eligibleForHouse && !eligibleForSenate)
    {
        System.out.println("The candidate is eligible for election to the House of Representatives but is not eligible for election to the Senate.");
    }
    if (!eligibleForHouse && !eligibleForSenate)
    {
        System.out.println("The candidate is not eligible for election to either the House of Representatives or the Senate.");
    }
    if (eligibleForHouse && eligibleForSenate)
    {
        System.out.println("The candidate is eligible for election to both the House of Representatives and the Senate.");
    }
}
```

}